# Add drop down menu to a custom masterpage in SHAREPOINT 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am making a Sharepoint 2010 masterpage from scratch using my own design. I want to add a custom drop down menu, but I am not able to find the correct code. Please suggest me correct steps to add a drop down navigation menu to my masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through below site. You can use SharePoint:ASPMenu control directly in Master page. You can render the value from Site Map xml.
http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2/

Answer (score 0):

Build a solution in Visual Studio 2010 and use the asp.net Menu control.
Package up the solution, deploy it to your sharepoint environment, and it will show as a web part when editing your master page in SharePoint Designer.  Just drag it into your project.

Or, just use SharePoint Designer and drop the ASP.NET Navigation Menu control from there.

Comment: I am a new person to SharePoint 2010 designer. Can you please provide me a walk-through guide how to customize the ASP.NET Navigation Menu once I have added it in SharePoint 2010 designer.